# anchor test: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I'm installing Solana on WSL following this guide:
https://github.com/LearnWithArjun/solana-env-setup/blob/main/mac_or_linux_setup.md

When I come to 'anchor test' I get this error:
anchor test

```
BPF SDK: /home/nick/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.13.0/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
/home/me/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried this:
https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4470

```
sudo apt install lsb
```

Didn't help.

This also doesn't seem to help
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421153/finding-libssl-on-a-customers-linux#421164

```
ldconfig -p|grep ssl
```

I also tried this which seemed to install fine, but didn't help anchor test:

```
sudo apt install libssl
```

How can I get `anchor test` to work?

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it, but you are trying to install the incorrect program.

Inside of your WSL terminal, try installing the `libssl-dev` package and a few others:

```
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev libssl-dev
```

If this still does not work, you can try to install the specific version of the `libssl` binary with these command:

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

PS: Great name! ;)

Comment: I should have said, already tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: haha yeah great name too

Comment: Gotcha, I just updated my response with the packages I had to install to get my setup working inside of Linux. Try giving those a try!

Comment: Just tried that, still didn't fix it :(

Comment: Try this updated method of manually installing the `libssl` version 1.1 binary

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error and I came across this command hope it helps
`Sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`