# Anchor test fails on Fedora

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-test, anchor-lang

I'm using Fedora 36 for dev but I am having trouble running `anchor test`. I get the following output:

```
cargo-build-bpf child: /home/0xAckerman/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
/home/0xAckerman/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found [this similar question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/anchor-test-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1?newreg=2828ca7cf62f41f6b4cdf801b71d0fff) but none of the answers work for Fedora. In particular, I've tried

```
sudo dnf install lsb
```

and

```
sudo dnf install openssl-devel
```

which is basically `libssl-dev` for Fedora but it's already installed on my system. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed it by downgrading to openssl1.1 using

```
sudo yum install openssl1.1
```

And `anchor test` finally works!

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users. I fixed it by installing the following lib.

Step 1:
`wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb`

Step 2:
`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb`