# Rust build fails - cannot find libssl.so

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cargo, build-bpf, build-sbf

The build fails due to error

```
/home/dev/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

OpenSSL and libssl-dev are already installed.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, same issue on Linux Mint as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anchor test: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/anchor-test-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1)

Comment: No, I found a fix to my problem and put it out here as a QnA for someone who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/issues/470) on the Solana Labs GitHub.

The solution is to download and install the `libssl` binary. The comments on the GitHub mentioned above issue specify a link to download the binary and install it.

All of the links return 404.

You can download the binary form the Ubuntu Packages link [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libssl1.1/download), the link is mentioned below the note.

If you click on the link, it might not get downloaded in your browser, copy and paste the link into a `wget` command and it'll download.

You can then install it. Here are the commands that worked for me as on 02/12/2023:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20_amd64.deb
```