# error while building using anchor

Tags: anchor

[image]

when I used anchor build , I am getting error

Comment: Hey! Would love to help get this fixed for you. Can you share a bit more information on your setup? Rust & Anchor versions + a look into your Cargo.toml would help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anchor test: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/anchor-test-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a duplicate, this has been asked a [couple of times before](https://solana.stackexchange.com/search?q=libssl.so.1.1).

Please, use the search before asking a question. It'll help you to get to the answer quicker and it helps keep this site from dupes.