How exactly do you install spl-token on Linux to transfer USDC using a CLI client?
I found the question of transferring tokens like USDC surprisingly under-documented. There's a StackOverflow question about it (until they delete it I guess) but I still couldn't figure out how to install this spl-token command.

Why isn't it included in the official solana binaries release? Seems important enough to be included there, no?

How do you install it anyway? I found https://spl.solana.com/token and per that page I had to install rust, then cargo, then the cargo install spl-token-cli command installed a lot of stuff then crapped out with some weird C compilation error. Why aren't there Linux binaries for this?



what error are you facing? is it related to this https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/anchor-test-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1

spl-token is included in the official binaries: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/f11b777e9bbbfdaa6550003ebe36c37331acd037/scripts/cargo-install-all.sh#L154-L157
